While I am creating versions of a document in OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph API getting Error : 400 Bad Request and invalidRequest
Here going to create versions (version history) of a document using this type of curl
POST /v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/versions
Content-Type: application/json


{
    "content": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileContent",
        "sourceUrl": "data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhCg=="
    }
}

but is the response I am getting error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid request",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-05-29T20:10:45",
            "request-id": "c1899a5f-e6d6-445d-b563-efb03268175c",
            "client-request-id": "c1899a5f-e6d6-445d-b563-efb03268175c"
        }
    }
}

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other Microsoft Graph API for creating versions.
In the response I expect 'Created' or 201 code, that means a new version of file or document added in version history.

I was experiencing the similar issue that is resolved now.
There is no such API to create a version which you are using "POST /v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/versions", you need to upload content of a new or different version with the same name and the version will be automatically updated, and you may see it on version history.
MS Graph API to upload content
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/FolderA/FileB.txt:/content
Content-Type: text/plain
The contents of the file goes here.

refence https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
